# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Database.Table>' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

Hello I am getting the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Database.Table>' to 'bool'
```

From this piece of code

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
  if (context.SomeTables.Where(p => p.FileName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)))
  {
      //Do Something     //above I am trying to compare if the filename in the db table
                         //is equal to the GetFileName being passed in but it throwing
                         //the error      
  }
```

Comment: Seems like you missing a `.Any()`, or just replacing the `Where` with Any altogether and put the expression in the Any. I'm not positive that will work with L2S though.

Comment: try context.SomeTables.Any(p...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
context.SomeTables.Where(p => p.FileName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))
```

returns an `IQueryable`, not a `bool`.  You need something that returns a `bool`, like

```
context.SomeTables.Any(p => p.FileName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))
```

as your condition for the `if` statement.

**See Also**
[Enumerable.Any Method (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To be more insightful, the if statement needs an expression that evaluates to true or false.  If you mouse over the Where() method you can see what it will be returning, which is a System.Linq.IQueryable.

Your error message is saying it needs a bool (true, false) but it's recieving System.Linq.IQueryable

Replacing Where() with Any() will return a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert suggested in his answer of using **Any()** in above case. this is good if you are just looking to compare true or false. In my opinion you might be looking for the object which you are comparing against the file object.

So you can also try like this.

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
 var tempvalue = context.SomeTables.Where(p => p.FileName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)).FirstOrDefault();
  if (tempvalue !=null)
  {
      //here you get both of the object file as well as compairer value.     
  }
}
```

This will give you the opportunity to get the tempvalue for further tasks. by this you get the value in single attempt and perform multiple tasks as well.

Comment: You may also write `context.SomeTables.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FileName == System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))`